# Oracle sql output format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in table like

```
Empid old_sal new_sal old_minsal new_minsal
1234    100       1000     10      999
.....
```

My requirement is to get data in the format:

```
Empid Property    old_val   new_val
1234    Sal         100       1000
1234    Minsal      10         999
.......
```

How I can get data in this format. Is it possible or I should change the table structure. Please advice.

Comment: Explain how did you get the second table from the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`:

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30480e/1)</sup>

```
select empid, 'Sal' property, old_sal old_val, new_sal new_val from test 
union all
select empid, 'MinSal', old_minsal, new_minsal from test
```